# When you create a Public Knowledge Base article, how do you see what URL it has?

Tags: knowledge, url, articles

Okay, I know you can set any URL you want on the Article, i.e. "MickeyMouse", but I don't understand at all what the prefix to that URL you set will be. How do you know? Will it be:

www.myorganization.force.com/MickeyMouse

?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Url will generaly point towards your Salesforce instance

https://yourInstance.salesforce.com

for Ex.
A recent dev org, will have https://na40.salesforce.com/articles/language/articleUrl

if you have a custom domain enabled, you will see https://yourcustomdomainname.force.com/articles/language/articleUrl

You can find details on Salesforce Url changes [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_app_url_changes.htm&type=0)

Comment: Is there a way to nest that public URL behind a site URL? Like, let's say my site url is na40.salesforce.com/examplesite, can I nest a public article like this: na40.salesforce.com/examplesite/articleUrl? so it's the affected by the site's robots.txt

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question for that one, thanks!